# Laravel: Is it bad practice to pass models to views?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

In the examples I have seen so far, concrete values are always passed to views - be it as separate variables, or as arrays.

Example from the Laravel documentation:

```
$view = View::make('greeting')->with('name', 'Steve');
```

Is it a bad idea to pass a model to a view?

In my **controller** I use:

```
return response->view('quote.render', Quote::find($id))
```

Instead of something like:

```
return response->view('quote.render', 
  ['date' => $quote->date,'clientName' => $quote->client->name, 'items'=> $quote->items])
```

And in my **view** (Blade template) I can then use the model like this:

```
To: {{$quote->client->name}
Date: {{$quote->date}}
```

The advantage for me is that I instantly have all my model's data on hand - and if the model changes (get's more attributes) I do not have to change my controller to pass the new data... It also feels cleaner.

**Are there any pitfalls to this approach? Or any reasons it is bad practice?** It feels right - but I don't see it in the examples.

Comment: In my opinion this is okay.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, the Laravel docs just contain a simple example to make the concept easier to understand. There's no point in having a complex example there when the bottom line is that you can pass data to the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is fine to pass a model into a view, a good way to do it is like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $thing = Thing::findOrFail($id);

    return view('showAThing')->with('thing', $thing);
}
```

Using `findOrFail()` in this context will throw a 404 error if the item doesn't exist in your database. This is useful because if you tried to render a view with `$thing` = `null` then you'd run into un-handled exceptions.

**Edit**

Editing to update this, `findOrFail` will not throw a 404 error automatically. It will throw a `ModelNotFound` exception, but you can set your error handler to catch this and do whatever you feel most appropriate (in my case I would return a 404 response).

Comment: And what if the model you pass in to View is mutable? You allow View to mutate Model, which could be database or some file or worse. View has no business being tied to Model, View should just be given the data it needs to output the UI by Controller (which in turns calls Model, Service, Repository, etc). View should not seep backover into the backend. This said, many argue in favour and Laravel made this popular, sadly imo

Answer (score 2):

**Liskov substitution principle**
objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program

**Dependency inversion principle** one should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions"

**Single responsibility principle**
a class should have only a single responsibility (i.e. only one potential change in the software's specification should be able to affect the specification of the class)

The view should not depend on a model nor should know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build something quickly or working on a project you know will not grow or maintain for a long time yes, otherwise you should consider abstracting your code more, see [SOLID PATTERN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: Is it possible to explain why passing a model to a view breaks the SOLID pattern? Or at least what principle it is breaking?